# How to load a page using a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, load

I'm using the jquery function `.load`:

```
$('div#content').load($lin '.entry-content');
```

How can I call a variable inside the brackets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a plus sign:

```
$('div#content').load($lin + '.entry-content');
```